# Can't change permissions on RAM disk

Tags: hard-drive, macos, memory, permission

Why can't I set root as folder owner?

```
diskutil erasevolume HFS+ "VTest" $(hdiutil attach -nomount ram://1165430)
cd /Volumes/VTest/
mkdir TDir
sudo chown root:wheel TDir/
ls -l
drwxr-xr-x  2 user  staff  68  7 янв 16:06 TDir
```

But it works fine for folders on any other drive(physical)

Comment: idk why, but just to confirm I can't either... or, to clarify, I can change perms but not owner/group.

Comment: What are the results with `sudo ls` ? I suspect the ram disk is mounted `noowners`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creating a RAM disk this way disables ownership. To enable ownership additionally enter:

```
sudo diskutil enableOwnership diskX
```

To add folders use `sudo mkdir folder_name`. The folder has root:wheel 755 permissions then, but you can change ownership to other users later.

Answer (score 0):

RAM is mounted `noowners`. You can change permissions of the files, but not change the owners.

The owner will be shown as the current user. Using the root user shows `_unknown`.

```
$ touch test
$ ls -l test
-rw-r--r--  1 grgarside  staff     0B  7 Jan 14:02 test
$ sudo ls -l test
-rw-r--r--  1 _unknown  _unknown   0B  7 Jan 14:02 test
```

Comment: If I do that on my RAM Drive the output for `sudo ls -l test` is `-rw-r--r--  1 me  staff  0 Jan  7 13:01 test` not `... _unknown  _unknown ...`. That said, I'm running OS X 10.8.5 at the moment and it may be different in later major releases of OS X and or macOS 10.12.